# Запуск Service из библиотеки

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-library

Есть библиотека, в которой есть `Service`. В `AndroidManifest` библиотеки  прописаны нужные `<uses-permission/>`, а так же сам Сервис `<service android:name="com.services.MyService"/>`.

Я подключаю эту библиотеку в своем проекте, и для того, чтобы нужный мне Сервис из библиотеки заработал — мне нужно прописать `permissions` аналогичные тем, которые прописаны в `AndroidManifest` библиотеки, и так же объявить `<service/>`.

**Вопрос:** можно ли каким-то образом нужные `permissions` и `<service/>` прописать программно, к примеру вызовом какого-то класса из библиотеки, который все нужные вещи пропишет сам, или пользователь в любом случае сам должен будет прописать это вручную?

**build.gradle (library)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

**build.gradle (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.project"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/MyLibrary.jar')
}
```

Comment: пермишены в своем манифесте дублировать ненужно. При компиляции происходит так называемый `manifest merge`, после которого манифесты объединяются в один общий. Программно пермишены можно запросить только в Android 6, и то я не уверен, что их не нужно предварительно прописывать

Comment: @metalurgus  я попробовал указать пермишены в библиотеке, а в приложении не указывать  и получил exeption с сообщением о том что нужно прописать пермишены, в случай когда манифесте библиотеки пермишены не указаны, но указаны в приложении - все работает нормально. Получается что  merge не работает так как хотелось бы.

Comment: а в какой IDE вы работаете? И чем собираете проект? (ANT, Gradle)?

Comment: @metalurgus AndroidStudio, Gradle.

Comment: Я вот прямо сейчас посмотрел, у меня библиотека использует Bluetooth, и соответствующие первишены, а основной проект использует библиотеку.  И я блютус пермишены прописал в манифесте только для библиотеки, а при компиляции манифест мержится в один общий

Comment: А можете показать ваши файлы build.gradle , может я что то  делаю не правильно.

Comment: к сожалению не могу, коммерческая тайна

Comment: @metalurgus а можете взглянуть на мои файлы Gradle ?

Comment: А, так вы же компилируете библиотеку, как jar. ПОчему вы не подключите ее, как модуль? У меня именно так, и только в этом случае merge будет работать.

Comment: @metalurgus отлично, это работает, можете дать ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключите вашу библиотеку не как `.jar` - файл, а мак модуль. В этом случае `manifest-merge` должен работать как положено.